# ∑ Log(i) = big theta(f(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given S(n) = ∑ Log(i) such that sigma runs from i=1 to n
What is a simple function f(n) so that the sum S(n) is in big Theta of f(n)?

I am thinking about f(n) = loglogn because I believe its within the boundaries of the initial value of the summation which is log1=0 and the terminal value of the summation which is logn.

Hence it would satisfy the definition of big theta..

Is this right? otherwise please help

Comment: S(n) = log(n!). Use Stirling's formula.

Comment: @n.m. I like deriving Stirling's formula rather than pulling out the magic tool. ;-)

Comment: Certainly not log(log(n)), this grows slower than the last term of the summation, log(n). It has to grow at least as fast !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture and convince yourself of the following.

The integral from 1 to N of log(x) is < ∑ Log(i) is < the integral from 1 to N+1 of log(x).

Therefore N log(N) - N < ∑ Log(i) < (N+1) log(N+1) - (N+1).

Both bounds are big Theta of N log(N).